# what does the alpha symbol represent in the standard equation used for inference by enumeration

Tags: probability, inference, bayesian-network

can anyone tell me what the alpha means in the following equation (used for inference by enumeration)?

[image: inference by enumeration equation]

Comment: Where did you find this equation?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the equation it could have meant $1/P(e)$ as the RHS sum is the joint distribution of $e$ and Cause; if every distribution/probability here was well-defined. But, apparently, we don't know it.

As rightly pointed out the in the comments, the notation used here is vague. $P(e)$, more explicit alternative might be $P_e(e')$, where $e$ represents the random variable/vector and $e'$ is one particular realization, and $P_e$ represents the PDF or PMF function of the random object $e$. Similar concern is valid for other expressions in the formula. This makes it harder to accurately answer the question.

The logic $\alpha$ being $1/P(e)$ stems from the following relation (assume $X,Y,Z$ are discrete RVs for simplicity):
$$p_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}{p_Y(y)}=\underbrace{\frac{1}{p_Y(y)}}_\alpha\sum_{z}p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)$$

So, considering we're interested in some RV or event, $X$, the denominator, i.e. $\alpha$ becomes merely normalizing constant, i.e. a scaler.

Comment: What do you mean by "$P(e),$" exactly?  What happened to "Cause"?  What if $P(e)=0$?  In brief, isn't $\alpha$ merely the requisite normalizing constant?

Comment: Trying to answer the question with so many assumptions is apparently a bad idea.